# Canvas flickering when reactjs re-renders

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, reactjs

I've got a problem using React JS and canvas together.

everything seems to work smooth, but when render method is called due to changes in other part of my app canvas flicker. It seems that react is re-appending it into the DOM (maybe because I'm playing an animation on it and its drawn frame is different each time).

This is my render method:

```
render: function() {
 var canvasStyle = {
   width: this.props.width
 };

 return (
   <canvas id="interactiveCanvas" style={canvasStyle}/>
 );
}
```

As a temporal solution I append my canvas tag manually, without reactjs:

```
render: function() {
var canvasStyle = {
  width: this.props.width
};
return (
  <div id="interactivediv3D">

  </div>
);
}
```

And then:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
var canvasStyle = {
  width: this.props.width
};

var el = document.getElementById('interactivediv3D');

el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + 
    '<canvas id="interactive3D" style={'+canvasStyle+'}/>';
 },
```

And it works right. But I think this is not a clean way and it's better to render this canvas tag using reactjs.

Any idea of how can I solve the problem? or at least avoiding reactjs re-rendering this canvas when only the drawn frame changed.

Comment: There's something else causing the re-rendering that you're describing. I created this simple jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/amq1t7jc/) that creates a canvas and then keeps overwriting the canvas every 16ms. It doesn't flicker as the canvas isn't being recreated.

Comment: Had the same issue, have  you tried addign a ref object to the canvas. then you can store and set the style attribute without re-rendering the whole component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spent time observing with your advice in mind and I find out this flickering was caused by the fact that I was accessing the canvas DOM element and changing canvas.width and canvas.height every time onComponentDidUpdate was called.

I needed to change this property manually because while rendering I don't know canvas.width yet. I fill style-width with "100%" and after rendering I look at "canvas.clientWidth" to extract the value in pixels.

As explained here: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html I attached resize event and now I'm changing canvas properties only from my resizeHandler.

Answer (score 4):

Re-rendering the entire tree shouldn't cause your canvas to flicker.  But if you think that re-rendering is causing this issue, you could use `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle function and return false whenever you don't want to to update.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

So for example:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return false;
}
```

Any component with the above function defined will not ever run `render` more than once (at component mounting).

However I've not been able to replicate the flickering issue you complain of.  Is your entire tree rendering too often perhaps? In which case the above will fix your canvas, but you should take a look at how many times and how often you are re-rendering your entire tree and fix any issues there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used `react-konva` library and my component structure looked something like this: canvas had a background image `<SelectedImage />` which flicked every time any state property changed.
**Initial code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Stage, Layer, Image } from "react-konva";
import useImage from "use-image";

function SomeComponent() {
    const [imgWidth, setImgWidth] = useState(0);
    const [imgHeight, setImgHeight] = useState(0);
    //...and other state properties

    const SelectedImage = () => {
        const [image] = useImage(imgSRC);
        if (imgWidth && imgHeight) {
            return <Image image={image} width={imgWidth} height={imgHeight} />;
        }
        return null;
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Stage width={imgWidth} height={imgHeight}>
                <Layer>
                    <SelectedImage />
                    {/* some other canvas components*/}
                </Layer>
            </Stage>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

**The solution**
The problem was in a wrong structure of `SomeComponent` where one component was initialized inside another. In my case it was `<SelectedImage />` inside of `SomeComponent`. I took it out to a separate file and flickering disappeared!
Here is a correct structure

**SelectedImage.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Image } from "react-konva";
import useImage from "use-image";

function SelectedImage({ width, height, imgSRC }) {
    const [image] = useImage(imgSRC);
    if (width && height) {
        return <Image image={image} width={width} height={height} />;
    }
    return null;
}

export default SelectedImage;
```

**SomeComponent.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Stage, Layer, Image } from "react-konva";
import SelectedImage from "./SelectedImage";

function SomeComponent() {
    const [imgWidth, setImgWidth] = useState(0);
    const [imgHeight, setImgHeight] = useState(0);
    //...and other state properties

    return (
        <div>
            <Stage width={imgWidth} height={imgHeight}>
                <Layer>
                    <SelectedImage width={imgWidth} height={imgHeight} imgSRC={imgSRC} />
                    {/* some other canvas components*/}
                </Layer>
            </Stage>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SomeComponent;
```